# How can I import component from variable or props - Dynamic router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, webpack, react-router

> *Context for a good solution (short question in bottom).*

I have a database (API) which generate list of data of apps like AppA, AppB, AppC, etc. with their name, path...

With a map, I generate (react router) links to these apps based on this data list (in the main `<App/>`) and front.
With another identical map (below), I have made the router which should call the App based on the route and app name:

```
function(Router) {
    const [routes, setRoutes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("MyAPI")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {setRoutes(result.results)}

            )
    }, [])

   // The route for each app and after the map, the route to the home with these links
    return (

        <Switch>{ 
            routes.map(result =>
                <Route exact path={"/"+result.route} key={keygen(16)}>
                    <AppCaller name={result.name} id={result.id} path={"/"+result.route}/>
                </Route>

            )}
            <Route exact path="/">
                <App />
            </Route>
        </Switch>

    )
}
export default Router
```

My first problem is I cannot neither give a component Name like `<result.name/>` from the API to call this component in the Router nor import dynamically this component.
My first solution was to create another component `<AppCaller/>` with the name and path as Props to remove the component problem like this :

```
import React from "react";
import Window from "./dashComponents"
import subApp from "./Apps/Store"

 class AppCaller extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <Window name={this.props.name}>
            <subApp/>
        </Window>
    )
  }
}

export default AppCaller
```

In fact, I can keep the `<subApp/>` name even if the app is different. The only thing i need to change is the "where" is the app comes **from**.

> *Begin of short question*

So, How can I change the path of the import statement to "import" the good App in this dynamic component ? (with a Props in this case)

```
import subApp from this.props.path
```

This may looks like this (if it was static):

`import subApp from "./Apps/App1"` in the App1 file

`import subApp from "./Apps/App1"` in the App2 file etc.

Another idea seen in React Documentation and in Stack Overflow is to use Lazy Import but it does not works:

```
import React, {Suspense} from "react";
import Window from "./dashComponents"
//import subApp from "./Apps/Store"

    const path = this.props.path
    let name = this.props.name

 function AppCaller() {

    const SubApp = React.lazy(() => import('./Apps/'+name))


    return (
        <Window name={name}>
            <Suspense fallback={<h2>"Chargement..."</h2>}>
                <SubApp/>
            </Suspense>
        </Window>
    )

}

export default AppCaller
```

OR

```
 class AppCaller extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const SubApp = React.lazy(() => import('./Apps/'+this.props.name));

    return (
        <Window name={this.props.name}>
            <Suspense fallback={"Chargement..."}>
                <SubApp/>
            </Suspense>
        </Window>
    )
  }
}

export default AppCaller
```

"The above error occured in one of your React Component..."

Thank you for your help.
I Try to be very accurate and find everywhere. So please, be free to tell me precision before judging.

**Edit 1 with full Error**

I have this error when I click in one of the links generated.

> The above error occurred in one of your React components:
> in Unknown (created by AppCaller)
> in Suspense (created by AppCaller)
> in div (created by Window)
> in Window (created by AppCaller)
> in AppCaller (created by RoutesX)
> in Route (created by RoutesX)
> in Switch (created by RoutesX)
> in RoutesX
> in div
> in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
> in BrowserRouter

> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
> Visit 'Facebook' to learn more about error boundaries.

**Edit 2 with initial Error**

> react-dom.development.js:11865 Uncaught ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed.
> (error: http://dash.localhost:8000/0.main.js)
> at Function.requireEnsure [as e] (http://dash.localhost:8000/static/frontend/main.js:106:26)
> at eval (webpack:///./src/components/AppCaller.js?:45:36)
> at initializeLazyComponentType (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?:1432:20)
> at readLazyComponentType (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js?:11862:3)
> ...
> requireEnsure @ main.js:106
> eval @ AppCaller.js:45
> ...

And

> 0.main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What is the full error message that appears when using `React.lazy`? You can click on [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64306281/edit) to include details to your question.

Comment: Thanks cbr for your answer, message edited with full error message

Comment: Could you include the error that the message refers to? It says "the above error" - please add that error.

Comment: Yes sorry, errors were filtered in chrome I did not see the the others errors :)

Comment: did you try using ES5 'require' instead

Comment: Looking at the error message, are you using Plotly Dash? If so, you'll need to add their [dynamic imports Webpack plugin](https://github.com/plotly/webpack-dash-dynamic-import) via `webpack.config.js`. So you'll need to `npm i @plotly/webpack-dash-dynamic-import` and edit `webpack.config.js` to add `const DynamicImportPlugin = require('@plotly/webpack-dash-dynamic-import')` and add `plugins: [ new DynamicImportPlugin() ]`

Comment: How Can i use require ? But I think there is a more modern solution :)
About Dash, it is my own Dash not from Plotly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Everybody !

So, it was not a React but a Webpack problem !

When you use a React lazy to import specific component, and you "compile" with `npm run dev (or build)` webpack split the code by Chunck but the configuration file is wrong.
Here's my configuration file which works:

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
    filename: 'App.js',
    publicPath: '/static/frontend/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I needed to add the "public path" to the path of the "chunck' scripts. :)